# how do you change an old bootstrap package without affecting the CSS in PHP

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I am trying to use an online bootstrap instead of the old bootstrap package that I was using for my code.  The problem is that with the online bootstrap, functionalities work  but it messes up with css and appearances and with the old bootstrap package, the css and appearances work but messes up the functionalities (datatarget to be specific)

I expected this to work well for my code but it didn't...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: How is this related to PHP? The problem seems to depend entirely on JavaScript packages.

Comment: Different Bootstrap big version numbers, that is going from v3 to v4, require a lot of changes in your code and CSS. See: [Migrating to v4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/) (note that the _whole page_ can be relevant)